# Depth of URLs and SEO

Tags: seo, url, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best stucture of SEO friendly URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/what-is-the-best-stucture-of-seo-friendly-url)

Does the depth of an URL affect SEO/Pagerank? Is there any max or optimal level for URL depth?

If you have, lets say, a website to map all the vegetarian local businesses (restaurants, shops, markets, etc.) in the world, which URL format would you choose?

1. `http://example.com/restaurant/name/city/country/1234`
2. `http://example.com/shop/name/city/1234`
3. `http://example.com/market/name/1234`

Comment: There's quite a few questions like that here on this site. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18225/seo-which-urls-are-the-best http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/squeezing-all-the-seo-out-of-a-url-as-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether you are trying to rank the leaves or the nodes. I.e. are you going for the "1234" page to be ranked or the "city" one? A deep structure favors the nodes, a flat the leaves. But it all depends on how the whole interlinking is done.